# Show Report group even when no records selected

Tags: crystal-reports, act

I'm trying to show employees at a company grouped by worked and still working (in vs2005 crystal reports). 
The user can pass by parameter a list of companies they want to show.

Tables: VRP-COMPANY, VRP-COMPANY-OPPORTUNITY, VRP-OPPORTUNITY-PRODUCT

The record selection formula: {VRP-COMPANY.COMPANY company} in {?companies}

Grouping is done on: VRP-COMPANY.COMPANY company, then formula to decide its working or worked and then on productname.

Now when I run the report I only get to see the companies who have got entries in the VRP-COMPANY-OPPORTUNITY. I want to see the company name (group) even if there are no entries in the opportunity table. How to do this in Crystal Reports? I tried Left join between company and company-opportunity tabel but no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Left join was correct but I had an additional select formula (on opportunity status to be closed-won. Therefore it let out the record. The record can also be null when there are no opportunities.

Should the question be deleted?